# Please help! After Pyrometra surgery

Tags: dogs, surgery

My dog had emergency pyrometra surgery on Jan 10th. She was discharged the 14th. Until today ( jan 28th ) her incison was healing very nicely and today it appear like this. I was in contact with the vet office today and they cannot get her staples out till feb 10th. When i mentioned the pink fleshy looking lump sticking out they told me it didnt seem like any major concerns. She is still eating and drinking no fever. And the incision area is not giving off any warmth..... My anxiety had been terrible since we almost lost her so this is really bothering me. [image]

Comment: Call your vet and ask them whether this is concerning and whether you should come by! Do not wait for people on the internet we are not experts!!

Comment: Ask the vet if you can send the picture to them via mail or any messaging app. If this should be an emergency but your current vet has no capacity to treat it, they should refer you to a different vet in your area. And maybe take a new photo because in the current one the most important part is blurry.

Comment: Have you gotten any feedback from your vet? You can write answers to your own questions here, which helps people who might have the same question in the future.